# Transaction not showing up as confirmed on MultiBit

Tags: synchronization, multibit-hd

I tried to send a Bitcoin transfer yesterday at noon and after more than 120+ confirmations it's still unconfirmed.
I used MultiBit as wallet, I set fees but still nothing.
I was used to super-fast transaction, the maximum I've waited in the past was 15 mins.

Did I do something wrong or is it just the usual time it takes?

Here it is:
https://blockchain.info/tx-index/ba8c1f8e3c2b526a0ed842eda8e6c75650c9ac12ba093b79b023556edf8bcec7

Comment: Is that MultiBit HD or MultiBit Classic? One of the original authors of MultiBit recommended not to use Classic anymore as it is outdated and no longer maintained.

Comment: It's the HD version

Answer (score 1):

A transaction cannot be both confirmed and unconfirmed. Your transaction is confirmed, just that your wallet is not showing you the right information. This is not normal behavior. This happens when your wallet is no longer synchronized with the rest of the network. You should be able to fix this by going to `Manage Wallet` and clicking the `Repair Wallet` button. Then follow the instructions in the dialog that appears.

Comment: @abraxas: You should consider accepting that answer if it helped you (and maybe upvote it)